# Replacing \n\r line feeds in php

Tags: php, xml, str-replace

I've written a small bit of php which gets items (products in this case) from an xml feed. I use simplexml_load_file to assign the various parts of the feed to variables.

It's working great and I'm outputting the results to a csv file. The problem I have is that some of the items in the xml are html descriptions and have line feed characters in them. This is breaking the csv as it sees these as new lines.

To solve this I've added an end of line string to each line of the csv and I'm trying to strip out all \n\r from the descriptions, then replacing the eol string with a \n which should make the csv work.

I can do it manually with notepad++ but when trying it with php it doesnt seem to work.

Below is the code I've tried but I might have messed something up as I've never done this before, and it doesn't seem to be working. The resulting csv still has the original line feeds and the eol string is still there.

```
//Get The Short and Long Descriptions from the $_item in the XML
   $short_Description = $_item->short_description;
   $description = $_item->description;

//OK now we need to firstly remove all the \n\r \n \r from the descriptions and once that's done replace "FEOL," with \n. Easy!

// Lets strip the LF and CR from the descriptions   
    $new_Line = array('\n\r', '\n', '\r');
    $replace = '';

    $short_Description = str_replace($new_Line, $replace, $short_Description);
    $description = str_replace($new_Line, $replace, $description);

// OK now we have one big long line lets add the CR or maybe LF back at the end of each line where we've put the FEOL place holder
    $eol   = 'FEOL,';
    $replace = '\r';

    $short_Description = str_replace($eol, $replace, $short_Description);
    $description = str_replace($eol, $replace, $description);
```

Just wondering if their's anything obvious that I'm missing, or maybe I'm going about it all wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Nigel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing "slash n" and "slash r" instead of LF and CR characters here:

```
$new_Line = array('\n\r', '\n', '\r');
```

Use double quotes:

```
$new_Line = array("\n\r", "\n", "\r");
```

You can see the difference yourself:

```
<?php
print '\n';
```

Will print: \n

While

```
<?php
print "\n";
```

Will print a newline character

Are you sure, that it should be "\n\r" and not "\r\n"?

Comment: That's it, Many thanks, it proves what I thought all along, I'm an idiot lol

Comment: @Go2Pub You don't need "\n\r" in $new_Line array at all - these symbols are replaced separately anyway

Comment: Yea I figured that out, I think I was just trying different combinations to see if I could get it to work before.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from the PHP documentation site:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '';

$newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);
```

As you can see, you should be using double-quotes around each array item and that you should be replacing `\r\n` not `\n\r` like you have been doing.